# python pygame blit. Getting an image to display

Tags: python, pygame, geometry-surface, blit

I'm trying to get my webcam to show video through pygame. Here is the code:

```
# import the relevant libraries
import time
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
# this is where one sets how long the script
# sleeps for, between frames.sleeptime__in_seconds = 0.05
# initialise the display window
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)

# set up a camera object
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0)
# start the camera
cam.start()

while 1:

    # sleep between every frame
    time.sleep( 10 )
    # fetch the camera image
    image = cam.get_image()
    # blank out the screen
    screen.fill((0,0,2))
    # copy the camera image to the screen
    screen.blit( image, ( 0, 0 ) )
    # update the screen to show the latest screen image
    pygame.display.update()
```

When i try this I get an error from the screen.blit( image, ( 0, 0 ) ) part

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\src\webcam.py", line 28, in <module>
    screen.blit( image, ( 0, 0 ) )
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

I assume It's because I didn't convert the image into whatever works with pygame, but i don't know.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

-Alex

OK so here is the new code: 
This one works because it saves the picture to the current folder. figured out why the last one work. the screen is still black although=\

```
# import the relevant libraries
import time
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
# this is where one sets how long the script
# sleeps for, between frames.sleeptime__in_seconds = 0.05
# initialise the display window
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
# set up a camera object
size = (640,480)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,0)


surface = pygame.surface.Surface(size,0,screen)

cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,size)
# start the camera
cam.start()

while 1:

    # sleep between every frame
    time.sleep( 10 )
    # fetch the camera image
    pic = cam.get_image(surface)
    # blank out the screen
    #screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # copy the camera image to the screen
    screen.blit(pic,(0,0))
    # update the screen to show the latest screen image
    p=("outimage.jpg")

    pygame.image.save(surface,p)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: ```cam.get_image()``` is returning ```None```.

Comment: The error implies that image is None, not that it is a valid image in the wrong format.  Apparently cam.get_image() failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a Camera like this.

```python
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0],(640,480))
```

That's how it's done on [this page](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html) of the pygame docs.

---

Looking at the [API page](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) for `pygame.camera`, I found two things that might help.  First,

> Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.
>
> EXPERIMENTAL!: This api may change or disappear in later pygame
>   releases. If you use this, your code will very likely break with the
>   next pygame release.

Keep that in mind when wondering why this surprisingly fails.

On a more up-beat note... you can try calling `camera.get_raw()` and printing the result.  It should be a string with raw image data.  If you get an empty string, `None`, or some non-sense text: please share that with us here.  It'll tell if you're getting anything from the camera.

> Gets an image from a camera as a string in the native pixelformat of the camera. Useful for integration with other libraries.

Comment: You may need to adjust the picture resolution, depending on your camera.

Comment: It doesn't find my camera that way. That's why i did it the other way and that part works fine. just the part that has to put the image onto the screen doesn't work

Comment: Ok, either way, ```get_image``` is silently failing.  So something before that isn't working.

Comment: Ok then i'm going to try a different way. I found a code that takes an image and saves it and it works. So i'm going to try to merge them. brb